# Get a process's owners, send them messagebox and then kill the processes

Tags: powershell, messagebox, countdowntimer, system-administration

I trying to get a list of users, who are running an application, for instance chrome.exe. Then send them a message and set the countdown timer for 300 seconds and after this I need to stop these processes. I have tried the following `PowerShell`.

```
$owners = @{} 
gwmi win32_process | % {
    $owners[$_.handle] = $_.getowner().user
}
get-process | select processname,Id,@{l="Owner";e={$owners[$_.id.tostring()]}}
```

---

### Answer was closed. below you can see a solution:

```
$USERLIST = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "Name='tsappldr.exe'" -ComputerName "SRUS270137C").getowner().user
ForEach ($computer in $USERLIST) {
$CmdMessage = {C:\windows\system32\msg.exe   $computer  /v 'Cancel your session'} $CmdMessage | Invoke-Expression 
}
Start-Sleep -m 5  #time-out for 5 minutes

get-process tsappldr, tpedrte  | stop-process -force
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everyone, who helped me, so i wrote current code:

```
$USERLIST = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "Name='tsappldr.exe'" -ComputerName "SRUS270137C").getowner().user
ForEach ($computer in $USERLIST) {
$CmdMessage = {C:\windows\system32\msg.exe   $computer  /v 'Cancel your session'} $CmdMessage | Invoke-Expression 
}
Start-Sleep -m 5  #time-out for 5 minutes

get-process tsappldr, tpedrte  | stop-process -force
```

And it works correct!

Answer (score 1):

Chrome usually start several process even if only one tab is opened. You'll need to select the unique user name to avoid several pop-up messges. You can use:

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "Name='chrome.exe'" -ComputerName "TargetPCName").getowner().user|select -Unique
```

Could you provide more info about the scenario that you have?

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can get the the process owner

`$(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "Name='chrome.exe'" -ComputerName client).GetOwner()`

And with this code you can display a messagebox.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Message")
```

And with Stop-process you can kill a process

When you have some errors with your code post it here, I will try to help

Comment: When i try to run `$(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "Name='chrome.exe'" -ComputerName client).GetOwner()` - i recieve a message:
**Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable.**

Comment: You have to change the computername. Client stands as **example**. If you want to execute it local then use localhost

Comment: Thanks for your help, the code `$(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "Name='chrome.exe'" -ComputerName "LRUS2701120").getowner().user|select -Unique` works.
So how can i set the array of users, and send them msgbox?

Comment: Take a look at the script from Rich Prescott [Script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Send-NetMessage-Net-Send-0459d235) 
And also make sure you have enabled remote powershell

Comment: so, i typed next code : `$USERLIST = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "Name='concentr.exe'" -ComputerName "SRUS270138C").getowner().user
ForEach ($computer in $USERLIST) {
       $CmdMessage = {C:\windows\system32\msg.exe *  $computer 'you have to cancel session in 5 minutes'}
       $CmdMessage | Invoke-Expression
    }` but this message displayed for all users, this loop shows n messages for n users, each user sees n messages...

Comment: Is more than one user logged in on the same time?

Comment: Sure, i completed this script and posted it below, Thanks for your time and advices, i'm really appreciate your help!